# Integration constant confusion (can I ignore it)

Tags: integration

I am computing a Physics problem, for which I am looking to prove that $P_{in}=P_{out},$ where P is power. This is in reference to a circuit, however, it is not the physics I am having a problem with.

My $P_{in}$ and $P_{out}$ are expressions which are dependent on currents $I_1$ and $I_2$.

I have derived $I_1$ and $I_2$ by solving the following:
$$L_2 V_1 \cos(wt)=L_2 m \frac{dI_2}{dt}+m^2 \frac{dI_1}{dt},$$
where:
$$L_2 \frac{dI_2}{dt}=-I_2R-m\frac{dI_1}{dt}.$$
Simply by substitution of the second equation into the first, I have obtained:
$$I_2=-\frac{L_2V_1\cos(wt)}{mR},$$
Now, by taking the derivative of the above:
$$\frac{dI_2}{dt}=\frac{L_2V_1w\sin(wt)}{mR},$$
and by substitution back into the first equation, where $m^2=L_1L_2$:
$$\frac{dI_1}{dt}=\frac{V_1\cos(wt)}{L_1}-\frac{L_2V_1w\sin(wt)}{RL_1}.$$
This is where I have a problem.

If I integrate the above expression:
$$\int dI_1=\int\frac{V_1\cos(wt)}{L_1}-\frac{L_2V_1w\sin(wt)}{RL_1}dt.$$
I get:
$$I_1=\frac{V_1}{L_1}\left[\frac{1}{w}\sin(wt)+\frac{L_2}{R}\cos(wt)\right].$$
If I then use this expression in attempt to prove that $P_{in}=P_{out}$

IT WORKS, i.e. it is shown that $P_{in}=P_{out}.$

My question is, surely if I am integrating indefinitely, surely there should be some integration constant, but if there was... I know the answer would be wrong because there would be an extra addition of C in one of the P equations, that isn't in the other (hence they would not be equal).

If anyone could clear this up for me that'd be great. Thanks.

Comment: You can just put boundary condition in with lower bound $I_1(t=0)$ and upper bound a general $I_1$ and similarly on the right-hand side with lower bound $t=0$ and upper bound $t$.

Comment: I had that thought, but surely as there is a factor of cos in the RHS, when t=0 the cos wouldn't cancel and there would be an extra addition of $-\frac{L_2}{R}$

Comment: what is your $I_1(t=0)$? Could it cancel that out?

Comment: I don't think it can, that is my problem...

Comment: Ignore me, I have just checked and I can't ignore the constant, however it does still cancel later on. Thanks for your help anyway